# unable to add Forms

Tags: c#, visual-studio

[image: добавление Forms]

Я добавил ссылку на формы Windows, но она выдает ошибку в обозревателе решений. что делать чтобы исправить ошибку?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: 1) вопросы здесь задают только на русском языке, перевееите ваш вопрос на русский или воспользуйтесь [Stack Overflow на английском](https://stackoverflow.com/) 2) чтобы узнать ответ на этот вопрос, нужно видеть содержимое .csproj файла. 3) если вам нужен Winforms проект, просто создайте его из шаблона Winfows Forms как новый проект.

Comment: спасибо, я уже решил проблему. Дело в том, что мне нужно было в один проект добавить ссылку на Forms. Я использовал стандартное консольное приложение, а нужно было использовать консольное приложение с помощью .NET.

Comment: Не в этом проблема была. Просто в новом .NET, от которого вы отказались, подключение форм делается [через файл проекта](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props-desktop) установкой свойства `UseWindowsForms` в `true`, тогда подключение пространства имён `using` сработает. А вы переключились просто на устаревший .NET Framework, где оно доступно по умолчанию. Но так и не сказали, зачем вам формы в консольном приложении. Возможо они были и не нужны.